# Second monitor cuts off borders

Tags: hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card, displayport, xrandr

My NVidia card has two outputs: DVI and DisplayPort. The DVI port goes directly to the DVI-input of the monitor and has no problems.

The DisplayPort has a DP-to-DVI adapter, with a DVI-to-HDMI cable plugged into it -- because my second monitor only has HDMI inputs.

`xrandr` lists *four* connections:

```
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    60.05    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93  
DP-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

The second monitor is Ok, but the edges of the picture are not shown... You notice it, when the maximized window has no borders shown...

The monitors are both 27" by ViewSonic, have native resolution of 1920x1080 and from the same model lineup -- just from different years.

Whatever is wrong with the DP->HDMI connection, can I somehow compensate for it by forcing certain parameters?

Forcing a lower resolution on the second screen fixes the problem of pixels "falling off", but distorts and otherwise diminishes the picture.

Trying to "set underscan" fails:

```
% xrandr --output DP-0 --set underscan on
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  11 (RRQueryOutputProperty)
  Serial number of failed request:  33
  Current serial number in output stream:  33
```

Comment: It's usually 'overscan' when the screen thinks it's a television picture rather than computer. The control is likely in the display's OSD.

Comment: Can't find anything like it in OSD... Can the computer tell monitor otherwise somehow?

Comment: Not sure, usually depends on the monitor. Try swapping the cables, see if the other one is affected the same way. My guess would be you have too many conversions going on for the EDID information to correctly pass between, causing it to have to guess.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my "solution" was to plug the HDMI cable into *the other HDMI-port* on the monitor. I gather, the manufacturer configures the two ports as "TV" and "Computer" out of the box.

Leaving the question open, as I'm curious, whether I could've made a difference with software/configuration instead -- such as by some clever use of `xrandr`...